# How and where do I install java 7?

Tags: java, installation

I need java 7 for my games to work. How do I install it? And from where? I didn't find a download anywhere. (I have macOS Mojave)

Comment: With Java being backwards compatible, I find it hard to believe that you need Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

try this: https://www.java.com/en/ and browse to get the desired version for you OS.